# MongoReplicaSetClient fails unexpectedly during primary re-election

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, replicaset

I'm working on migrating our codebase which refers to mongo resources to using replication and I am seeing some unexpected behavior from the MongoReplicaSetClient. The client works fine unless I attempt a write during the time that a new primary is being is being elected.

The simple test I'm running is:
 * Start up a 3 node replica set
 * Connect with MongoReplicaSetClient('localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27017', replicaSet='rs0'
 * Perform a write
 * Kill the primary and immediately perform a write
 * Perform another write after primary election has completed

All the above steps work fine except for the second to last where the primary is down. According to the [MongoReplicaSetClient](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.html) documentation I would expect an [AutoReconnect](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html#pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect) error to be thrown for all write attempts executed while no primary exists. However, what I'm seeing instead is a generic AssertionError.

```
db = MongoReplicaSetClient('localhost:27017,localhost:27018,localhost:27017', replicaSet='rs0', w=2).testdb
db.testcol.save({'test': 1})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 266, in save
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 362, in insert
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/message.py", line 248, in _do_batched_insert
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py", line 1456, in _send_message
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymongo/pool.py", line 397, in maybe_return_socket
AssertionError
```

Does anyone know if this is expected behavior? I'd like to handle this type of event properly or even block all writes until election has completed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if re-election goes down as a connection error, rather "no candidate servers found" would go down as a connection error

Comment: It is a bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-601

Comment: Is there any difference between MongoClient and MongoReplicaSetClient at this point? The documentation states that it runs a monitoring thread for keeping tabs on the replica set. However, I ran the same test as above using MongoClient and it was able to detect the primary change just fine. It also threw the appropriate AutoReconnect error as expected during primary election. I'm wondering if the docs are just out of date and MongoReplicaSetClient is on a deprecation path.

Comment: Hi, I'm a PyMongo maintainer. MongoReplicaSetClient is definitely not on a deprecation path; in fact, it's the preferred way to connect to a replica set. The reported error is a bug, which we'll fix in the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported error is a bug, which we'll fix in the next release, PyMongo 2.7. The bug is described here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-601